# Detect cycles in a linked list with topological sort

Tags: algorithm

Given the following linked list

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> C (same C as earlier)
```

I need to find a way to detect cycles.

Can't I just view this as a graph and do a topological sort?
If that fails, there's a cycle in the list?

Comment: Exactly: [Khan's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Kahn's_algorithm) gives you "cycle detection for free" (in the sense that while you do the sorting, you also check for cycles, so you do not need extra work to detect the cycle)

Comment: So your linked list is not really a list. In particular, in your example, C is connected to B, E, and D.

Comment: Or `Floyd's algoritm`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a topological sorting algorithm that detects cycles, or you can use the special structure of the linked list by marking the nodes you have already visited, at the expense of incurring in one bit of memory overhead per node. It would work as follows: Initially all visit bits are set to 0. You enter a node. If its visit bit is set to 1, you have already visited, and so you have a cycle and you can end your program. If not, set the visit bit to 1 and move to the next node in the list. If you reach the end of the list and you never found a bit set to 1, then there are no cycles. If you cannot afford this extra bit in the node, you can do this outside with a hash table (this might be overkill though).

Essentially if you have a linked list with no cycles, then you already have a linear ordering of your nodes which is what topological sorting outputs, so checking for cycles (in this special case) would just be a verification of the potential ordering given by the linked list.